# Autosave with ajax, php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I tried to write a script mixing something I found on the internet in order to autosave a form data to the mysql db... Something went wrong cause the script it is able to insert but for some reason not to update so every 20 sec (the time I set up) is generating a new row... Can anyone help me to find and solve the issue? 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['article_id']); 
require_once('xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php');
$xajax = new xajax();

function savetodb($form) {
    $title = $form["title"];
    $editor = $form["editor1"];

    //$host = 'localhost'; 
    //$username = 'my_user';  
    //$password = 'my_pass'; 
    //$database = 'test_db'; 
    //$connect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    //mysql_select_db($database, $connect);

    if ($_SESSION['article_id']=="") {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO draft (`title`, `content`) VALUES ('$title', '$editor')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
        $idlast = mysql_insert_id($connect);
        $_SESSION['article_id'] = $idlast;
    } else {
        $article_id = $_SESSION['article_id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE draft SET `title`='$title',`content`='$editor' WHERE `id`='$article_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
    }
    // Instantiate the object xajaxResponse
    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
    $objResponse->assign("autosavemsg","innerHTML", "<br />Record saved to database successfully!");
     $objResponse->alert('Done!');
    return $objResponse;

}
//$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION,'savetodb');
$xajax->registerFunction('savetodb');
$xajax->processRequest();
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<?php $xajax->printJavascript('xajax'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
echo '<label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br /><br />';
echo '<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>' ;
?>
<input type="button" name="save" onclick="xajax_savetodb(xajax.getFormValues('form'));" value="Save to Database">
</form>

<div id="autosavemsg"></div>

<script language="Javascript">
//Interval
var AutoSaveTime=20000;
//time object
var AutoSaveTimer;
SetAutoSave();
function SetAutoSave() {
  AutoSaveTimer=setInterval("xajax_savetodb(xajax.getFormValues('form'));",AutoSaveTime);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately is not even give to me the alert "done" or the message that I set..
**Probably something wrong with the session??** 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `xajax` but referring to my logic, I think you are doing it wrong.

I think you have to have two different files, one is your `HTML` and `javascript` and other one is your server-side code which is responsible for inserting or updating the `db`.

right now as I think you are calling the file itself with `ajax` and in the third line of the code you have `unset($_SESSION['article_id']);` which will unset the *session variable* `$_SESSION['article_id']` each time you call the `ajax`.

so I think you have to make two different files.

**file1.php**
you have your `html` and `javascript` files in it and also have the  `unset($_SESSION['article_id']);` line in it.

**files2.php** you have your `php` and `db related functions` in it and delete the `unset($_SESSION['article_id']);` line from it.

you also have to set in *file1.php* that your `ajax` should call *file2.php*

I think this will do the trick

Comment: I also try to remove the unset session but still not working.. It seems that is not setting the id in the session

Comment: it's a bit weird. have you tried my suggestion regarding to making two different files? if so, can you please edit your original post and update it with your new code and content of two files?